# Trouble accessing fields of a serialized object in Java

Tags: java, serialization, object, stream

I have instantized a class that `implements Serializable` and I am trying to stream that object like this:

```
try{
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
    ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    toServer.writeObject(myObject);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

All good so far right?  Then I am trying to read the fields of that object like this:

```
//This is an inner class
class HandleClient implements Runnable{

private ObjectInputStream fromClient;
private Socket socket; // This socket was established earlier

try {
    fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    GetField inputObjectFields = fromClient.readFields();

    double myFristVariable = inputObjectFields.get("myFirstVariable", 0);
    int mySecondVariable = inputObjectFields.get("mySecondVariable", 0);

    //do stuff

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fromClient.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I always get the error:

`java.io.NotActiveException: not in call to readObject`

This is my first time streaming objects instead of primitive data types, what am I doing wrong?

**BONUS**

When I do get this working correctly, is the ENTIRE CLASS passed with the serialized object (i.e. will I have access to the methods of the object's class)?  My reading suggests that the entire class is passed with the object, but I have been unable to use the objects methods thus far.  How exactly do I call on the object's methods?

In addition to my code above I also experimented with the `readObject` method, but I was probably using it wrong too because I couldn't get it to work.  Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

You need to use `ObjectInputStream.readObject` to deserialize. You cannot read individual fields from the stream*.

```
fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object myObject = fromClient.readObject();
```

Don't forget to flush the output stream when writing!

The second question is a little more complex. What the serialization mechanism does is write a class identifier to the stream followed by the serialized object data. When it deserializes it will read the class identifier and attempt to load that class (if it isn't already loaded). It will then instantiate the object using the no-arg constructor and call the private `readObject(ObjectInputStream)` method. Yes, that's right, it calls a private method from outside the class. Java serialization is special.

If the class cannot be found (i.e. if it's not on the classpath) then an exception will be thrown; otherwise you'll get a fully deserialized object of the correct type assuming no other errors are found.

For example, suppose you have the following classes:

```
class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set up an OutputStream sink, e.g. writing to a socket (not shown)
        ...
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sink);
        out.writeObject(new Data("data goes here"));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}

class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set up an InputStream source (not shown)
        ...
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(source);
        Data d = (Data)in.readObject();
        System.out.println(d.getData());
    }
}

class Data implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String data;
    public Data(String d) {
        data = d;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Now suppose you put those classes into three jars (one class per jar): server.jar, client.jar and data.jar. If you run the following commands then it should all work:

```
java -cp server.jar:data.jar Server
java -cp client.jar:data.jar Client
```

But if you do this:

```
java -cp server.jar:data.jar Server
java -cp client.jar Client
```

then you'll get a `ClassNotFoundException` because the client doesn't know how to find the `Data` class.

Long story short: the class itself is not written to the stream. If deserialization succeeds then you will have access to the object as though it had been created locally, but you will have to downcast the result of `readObject` to the expected type.

There is some complexity around versioning that I've ignored for now. Take a look at `serialVersionUID` and how to deal with changes to serializable classes if versioning is likely to be an issue.

*Not strictly true. You can call `readFields` inside the serializable object's `readObject` method (or `readResolve`), but you cannot call it from outside the deserialization mechanism. Does that make sense? It's a little hard to explain.

Comment: thanks, you cleared up two important points for me.  I didn't realize that BOTH the "server" and "client" needed local copies of the class in question.  I also did not realize that I needed to cast the object type.  I think all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for `ObjectInputStream.readFields()`, that exception is called because the `curContext` field is null.  You should call `fromClient.readObject()` before calling `readFields()`, as it will set the `curContext`.  Note that `readObject()` will return the instance that is being serialized, which may be of more use to you.